# Cookie problem for Laravel Sanctum on local dev environment

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-sanctum

I am working locally on a project where my Laravel backend is running by Laravel Valet on the url https://backend.app and my frontend is a Vue project running on http://localhost:8080.

When I do the call from my frontend to my backend to generate the CSRF token I get a 200 response but I get a warning next to the Set-Cookie header that says:

> This Set-Cookie was blocked because it has the "SameSite=Lax"
> attribute but came from a cross-site response which was not the
> response to a top-level navigation.

I can imagine that it can't work when my backend runs on backend.app and my frontend runs on localhost. Any tips or ideas how to get this to work on my local environment?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: do u find solution ?

Comment: I am running my backend using docker now. Everything runs on localhost now. You could look into Laravel Sail if you are not familiar with Docker. I didn't use it but I think it will give the same result.